# #include "~/file_name" doesn't compile

Tags: c

I have 2 programs:

```
#include "file1"

int main(void)
{
    return (1);
}
```

where file1 is just an empty file located in the same directory as the program.

Then I have:

```
#include "~/file2"

int main(void)
{
    return (1);
}
```

where file2 is an empty file but this time is located in my home directory.

The first program compiles, the second program complains and says `file not found`

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: `~` is expanded by the *nix **shell**, it doesn't have any special meaning outside of a shell (or at least, not in a C include file name).

Comment: ~ is not a special character for C processor.

Comment: I think preprocessor code can't understand that `~` is your home directory. Try the full path instead (E.G. `/home/username/file2`)

Comment: Why not generate extended preprocessed code with -E switch and see what went wrong? -E.g gcc -E filename.c

Comment: Why would you want to use `~` in the C code anyway? That means if someone else compiles the program they need to have that file in their own home directory. C source code should be self-contained, not dependent on the environment of the user who compiles it. If you really want to do something like that, do it in a configure script.

Answer (score 3):

A directive like:

```
#include "file.h"
```

searches for a file whose name is `file.h`. The string `~/file2` in your example is not actually the name of a file. The `~` is expanded *by the shell* to the path of your home directory; the actual file name is something like `/home/username/file2`.

The mapping of strings to files can be complex, and it can vary from system to system, but in general there's a fair amount of syntax that's recognized by the shell and *converted* to a file name, but that doesn't form a file name itself. Variable names like `$HOME` are similar; you couldn't use `$HOME` in a `#include` directive.

Actually

```
#include "~/file2"
```

*could* be valid -- if you have a directory whose name is literally `~` containing a file whose name is `file2`. That would be legal but confusing.

You could use

```
#include "/home/username/file2"
```

but that ties the source to your particular home directory and would make it difficult for anyone else to use ut.

Usually a file to be included should have a name ending in `.h`, and its location should be either relative to the directory containing the source file, or in one of several locations searched by the compiler.